# JQuery get multiple values in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get values of different divs. I have 18 choices. When I select a div the class of the div becomes `.sm-select` through JS code. I can select a maximum of 4 divs and I want to get the values of the divs like: "value 1, value 4, value 6, value 12", and store them in a hidden input field. The values are text strings.

However, presently I have only the first one when I use ".attr('value')" with my code and I display it in a input type text to test it.

Can someone may enlighten me how I can do this? Thank you.

My HTML :

```
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" value="Expo">
        <p>Expo</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" value="Extrême">
        <p>Extrême</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" value="Spa">
        <p>Spa</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" value="Nature">
        <p>Nature</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 whichenvie">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

My JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.sm-envies').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function (){
            var Envie = $('.sm-select').attr('value');
            $( ".whichenvie>input" ).val(Envie);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(".whichenvie > input").val($(this).val() + ',' + Envie)` ? maybe this?

Comment: you have got only the first one, becuase the jquery class selector returns an array...i feel like i typed it like 1000 times xD you need to loop over your HTMLCollection, just like you did with the each() function AND you need do add data- before your "value -> `data-value="yourValue"`

Comment: Replicate your issue in a fiddle for us to be able to help you. And, a `div` element doesn't have a `value` attribute. Use custom `data-*` attributes if need be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the `attr` function on a jQuery object will return only the attribute value of the first element found by the selector. To get the attribute value of all elements you will have to iterate over the objects using the `each` function:

```
$(function () {
    $('.sm-envies').click(function () {
        var Envie = '';
        $('.sm-select').each(function () {
            Envie += $(this).attr('value') + ';';
        })
        $(".whichenvie>input").val(Envie);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In html you cannot create custom properties unless you prepend them with 'data-', in this case 'data-value'. If the element was an input instead of a div you could use 'value'.

```js
$(function(){
  // this binds the click event to all divs of class .sm-envies
  // no need to do an each thanks to jquery
  $('.sm-envies').on('click', function(){
    var envie = $(this).data('value');
    $(".whichenvie > input").val(envie);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
  <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="Expo">
    <p>Expo</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
  <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="Extrême">
    <p>Extrême</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
  <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="Spa">
    <p>Spa</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
  <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="Nature">
    <p>Nature</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 whichenvie">
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This JS code should work:

```
$('.sm-envies').on('click', function (e){
    $( ".whichenvie>input" ).val($( ".whichenvie>input" ).val() + ', ' + $(e.target).text());
});
```

See: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leofcx/qhz69t7o/)

Answer (score 0):

set a counter to count,

```
var counter = 0; 
var maxCount = 4; 
var answer = array(); 

$('.example').on('click', function() {
     if(counter<maxCount) {
     var thisVal = $(this).val(); 
     answer.push(thisVal); output answer as array
     } else {
          $('input').val(''); // set all value to empty 
          answer = []; // empty array
          counter = 0; // reset counter 
     }
     counter++
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). This also allows you to select only 4 options.

```js
$(".col-xs-6").on("click", ".sm-envies", function() {
    
    if ($(".sm-select").length >= 4 ) {
        alert ("you've already selected 4 options!\nThey are " + $("input:text").val());
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass("sm-select");
    var vals = $(".sm-select").map(function(val) {
        return $(this).data("value");
    }).get().join(",");
    
    $("input:text").val(vals);
});
```

```css
.sm-select {
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="Expo">
        <p>Expo</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="Extrême">
        <p>Extrême</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="added1">
        <p>added1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="added2">
        <p>added2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="Spa">
        <p>Spa</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 sm-6">
    <div class="decale sm-envies envie" data-value="Nature">
        <p>Nature</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 whichenvie">
    <input type="text" style="width: 300px" />
</div>
```